# Internet Explorer COM Automation Object refreshes on visibility change

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, com

On a Delphi application, I am using TWebBrowser (which is wrapper around Internet Explorer's COM object) to create the UI.

When I change the visibility of the window hosting the TWebBrowser, e.g.: when I minimize it to the tray, the TWebBrowser triggers a refresh of the page, thus causing the page that was displayed on the TWebBrowser to lose its state.

This happens both when I minimize the window and when I restore it.

Is there any way to override this behavior?

Comment: This doesn't happen to *usual* pages; could you post the URL to a site with which this happens to you ? Or does it happen with all pages you navigate to ? And if so, are you sure you have no extra code that might cause it ?

Comment: It happens with all the pages that I navigate to, and it happens both when I make the form invisible or when I configure it not to be displayed on the taskbar (Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := false).

There is no extra code that could have triggered such a behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that *minimize to tray* part. However, I can't simulate what you've described in Delphi 2009. What version of Delphi are you using ? Could you add a minimalistic code that you're using to hide and show the form (it should be just few lines) ? Could you edit your question and add these information, please ?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following resources to troubleshoot:

- [Focus is not set to the Web page if you minimize the browser window and then maximize it from the taskbar in Internet Explorer 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936949)
- [The Window.focus method does not work in Internet Explorer 8](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979954)